# javascript document evaluate a string

Tags: javascript, string, document, evaluate

Is it possible to use document.evaluate on html code that is in a string ?
Inserting the html in my document is not an option because it originates from another random domain,so it's unsafe code.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean can you use `document.evaluate` to look inside something like `<h1>Hello, I have a <p>p tag</p> but not really.</h1>` to find the p tag, then no I don't think that's possible. I would suggest using a regEx to search for such things.